# I want to replace the values of x and X in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a transposed data frame which is

new_ttt_try:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | True_values | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A | T | T | F | NA | 2 | 0.1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| B | T | T | F | NA | 2 | 0.1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| C | NA | T | F | NA | 1 | 0.0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D | F | T | F | NA | 1 | 0.0 |

example:

| id | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | X | X | F | NA |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | x | X | F | NA |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | NA | x | F | NA |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | x | x | F | NA |

I am trying

```
column_mapping = {}
columns = new_ttt_try.columns
for col in example.columns:
   if col in new_ttt_try.index:
       frequency_value = new_ttt_try[new_ttt_try.index==col]['Freq'].values[0]
       column_mapping[col]= frequency_value
for col,frequency_value in column_mapping.items():
#print(type(col))
#example = pd.DataFrame(example)
   if col in example.columns:
       example['cis sub controls'].replace({"X": frequency_value, "x": frequency_value},      inplace=True)
```

Output expected:

| id | A | B | C | D | Sum_freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | F | NA | 0.2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 | F | NA | 0.2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | NA | 0.1 | F | NA | 0.1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 0.1 | 0.1 | F | NA | 0.2 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
freqs = []
for i in range(len(example)):
  freq = 0
  for j in example.columns:
    cell = example.at[i,j]
    if cell == 'x' or cell == 'X':
      example.at[i,j] = new_ttt_try[new_ttt_try['Unnamed: 0'].eq(j)]['Freq'].values[0]
      freq += example.at[i,j]
  freqs.append(freq)
example['Sum_freq'] = freqs
print(example)
```

the output will be :

[image: output]

Comment: It is an example data but the real time data has different frequency values

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check it out.

Comment: Hello Jordy, thanks for the update I have tried and made some changes in the code but here is the issue

Comment: The following columns still contain 'x' or 'X': ['action.hacking.variety.use of stolen creds', 'action.social.variety.pretexting', 'action.malware.variety.unknown', 'action.social.variety.pretexting', 'action.malware.variety.other', 'action.hacking.variety.other', 'action.hacking.variety.use of stolen creds']

Comment: Can you provide your csv file anywhere, so i can download and test it?